# strstr No encuentra carácter diagonal en C

Tags: c

quiero remplazar una cadena pero me resulta el problema que no trabaja si el string contiene un diagonal

```
 char *str_replace(char *orig, char *rep, char *with) {
      int strlen_orig = strlen(orig);
      int strlen_rep  = strlen(rep);
      int strlen_with = strlen(with);char * tmp;
      if(strlen_orig == 0 || strlen_rep == 0 || strlen_with == 0) return orig;


      tmp = strstr(orig, rep); 
      if(tmp != NULL ){
                strncpy (tmp,with,strlen(with)); printf("ENCONTRO");
      }

      return orig;
}
```

funcion que llama

```
 str_replace(buf,(char*)"</form>",(char*)"</form><h1>ola</h1></form>"));
```

si uso por ejemplo

```
 str_replace(buf,(char*)"<form>",(char*)"</form><h1>ola</h1></form>"));
```

trabaja, muchas gracias.

Comment: No funciona, se me hace raro por que no es un caracter especial.

Comment: Nada :/ aun no lo reconoce

Answer (score 0):

No es un tema de escapar los caracteres, tan sólo que los estas pasando invertidos a la función `strstr`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *Cadena = "</form><h1>hola</h1></form>";
    char *CadenaABuscar = "</form>";

    char *tmp = strstr(Cadena, CadenaABuscar); 
    if(tmp != NULL )
        printf( "Encontrada");
    else
        printf( "No encontrada");

    return 0;
}
```

La salida de este ejemplo es:

> Encontrada

En tu caso, en el código:

```
tmp = strstr(orig, rep);
```

¿No debiera ser...?:

```
tmp = strstr( with, rep );
```

Comment: No, por que buscaria lo que remplazaria con lo que quiero remplazar.

Comment: Como puedes ver @MrJhon, al función `strstr` funciona correctamente. Lo único que nostros no sabemos el contenido de la variable orig.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que debes separar memoria ya que el nuevo string tendrá una longitud mayor al del inicial.

El algoritmo que implemente separa en 3 partes el string(parte 1 antes del substring; parte 2, el substring; part3 despues del substring). Luego copia todo el string a otro string que tenga la longitud final, después búscamos ese substring y obtenemos el índice, despues copiamos el nuevo substring reemplazando al anterior, despues copiamos el resto.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *str_replace(char *orig, char *rep, char *with) {
    int strlen_orig = strlen(orig);
    int strlen_rep  = strlen(rep);
    int strlen_with = strlen(with);
    if(strlen_orig == 0 || strlen_rep == 0 || strlen_with == 0) return orig;

    int strlen_out = (strlen_orig- strlen_rep + strlen_with);

    char *out = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen_out+1));
    out = memcpy(out, orig, strlen_orig);
    char *tmp = strstr(out, rep);
    if(tmp != NULL){
        int start = tmp -out;
        memcpy(&(out[start]), with, strlen_with);
        memcpy(&(out[start + strlen_with]), &(orig[start + strlen_rep]), strlen_orig - start - strlen_rep);
        out[strlen_out+1] = '\0';
        return out;
    }

    return orig;
}

int main()
{
    char *buf = "ppp</form>hhh";
    char *rep = "</form>";
    char *with = "</form><h1>ola</h1></form>";

    char * out = str_replace(buf, rep, with);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    printf("%s\n", out);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ppp</form>hhh
ppp</form><h1>ola</h1></form>hhh
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Pero no me funciona tu ejemplo.

Comment: @MrJhon que sale cuando lo ejecutas.

Comment: No sale nada, puse un _print_ dentro de _if(tmp != NULL){_ pero nunca llo muestra estando el contenido que quiero remplazar.

Comment: @MrJhon cuales son los parámetros que has colocado??

Comment: @MrJhon podrías mostrar esa petición ya que la respuesta podría contener el caracter '\0', por lo que strstr podría fallar.

Comment: De hecho en el ejemplo que di funciona pero no se porque el _/_ da problemas, alguna idea?

Comment: ¿en qué sistema operativo estás trabajando?

Comment: Windows 10, _strstr_ posee algun limite o solo funciona con caractes alfabeticos ? por que ni con numero ni _<_

Comment: Y se esta colgando el programa, si es mayor en longitud la variable _with_

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51262/discussion-between-mr-jhon-and-eyllanesc).